# Twisted + qtreactor: How to cleanup after last window closed?

Tags: python, pyqt, twisted

I have a Twisted/PyQt application that (among other things) connects to a bunch of remote resources. When the user closes the window I want to shut down all the connections, cleanly if possible, forcibly if not.

The problem is that by the time I go to close the connections, it appears that the reactor is no longer alive to let me do so.

Here's my app code:

```
# Create app and connect the Twisted/Qt reactors
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
qtreactor.qt4reactor.install()

# Shutdown Twisted when window is closed
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def stop():
    print "="*40, "Closing connections..."
    yield closeConnections()
    print "="*40, "closed."

    print "="*40, "Stopping reactor..."
    reactor.stop()
    print "="*40, "stopped."
app.connect(app, SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"), stop)

reactor.runReturn()
rc = app.exec_()
exit(rc)
```

And here's a stripped down version of my cleanup code:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def closeConnections():
    for connection in connections:
        print "Closing connection #%s" % connection
        yield threads.deferToThread(popen("/foo/bar/cleanup %s" % connection))
        print "Connection closed."
```

The first print statement is reached, and the command is executed, but I never get the second one, nor do I go through the for loop multiple times.

Is my analysis correct? Is the problem that the reactor is already down, so I never hear back from threads.deferToThread? Or is there some other problem? Furthermore, how do I fix it?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly when that ***lastWindowClosed()*** signal fires.  However, even if it fires early enough, before the reactor has shut down (preventing you from doing what you want to do), I'm sure that PyQt doesn't know what to do with the Deferred that is returned by your `stop` function.  This means that the shutdown process will proceed merrily onward while your asynchronous cleanup code tries to run.  Likely the GUI shutdown will finish before your network shutdown gets anywhere.

So, use `reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before', 'shutdown', stop)` instead.  I don't know if this will run slightly earlier or slightly later than ***lastWindowClosed()***, but it will run early enough that the reactor will still be usable, and it **will** pay attention to the Deferred your function returns.  Shutdown will be suspended, in fact, until that Deferred fires.  This gives you all the time you need to do your cleanup.

Separately from all that, you shouldn't do `threads.deferToThread(popen("/foo/bar/cleanup %s" % connection))`:

- You need to pass a callable to `deferToThread`, not the result of calling the callable.  As written, your code runs popen in the reactor thread and passes a file object to the thread to be called (which makes no sense, of course)
- Mixing threads and child processes is iffy.  You might get away with it most of the time, I dunno.
- `reactor.spawnProcess` will let you run a child process without blocking, without threads, and without worrying about mixing threads and processes.  See also `twisted.internet.utils.getProcessOutput` if you don't need all the features of `spawnProcess` (which you appear not to).

Comment: Paul:
Sorry, my `popen(...)` wasn't real code. I have a more complex connection mechanism that is a combination of shell commands to start up remote clients and TCP connections to interact with them. I chose not to complicate my example with the details, and in doing so got my `closeConnection()` code wrong. My bad.

Thanks! Changing it to use `reactor.addSystemEventTrigger('before', 'shutdown', stop)` worked like a charm. Now the reactor is still alive when I'm doing my callbacks, and they all work as expected.

Comment: Also, I found a bug. When I do the above, the reactor is stopped but my program doesn't quit. Turns out that when I call `reactor.stop()`, qtreactor doesn't call `reactor.threadpool.stop()` and ThreadPool threads are left running (as shown by `threading.enumerate()`). Then when I manually call `reactor.threadpool.stop()`, the program exits. qtreactor's `stop()` should take care of this.

So should I file a bug report for this issue? If so, where? DeferToThread is a great way to interface with legacy library code that is blocking (as I do), so this isn't a feature I can/should do without.

Comment: One thing to try is the PySide-based Qt reactor.  We're trying to re-incorporate that into Twisted because the PySide license is compatible (the PyQt license is not).  If that reactor also exhibits the problem, please do file a ticket or leave a comment on http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3977

Comment: I'm working on porting to PySide; when I do I'll try the official reactor for that.